# Jenkins permissions while deploying Symfony3 web application (clearing cache)

Tags: php, jenkins, deployment, symfony

I'm deploying a Symfony3 application via Jenkins on Ubuntu. I'm clearing the cache by running the `cache:clear --env=prod` command after all the other commands (using shell command in Jenkins).

After clearing the owner of the new cache files is Jenkins, so my Symfony3 application does not load via browser telling me it has no permission to work with the cache and logs folders.

How can I make Jenkins clearing the cache and return the folders owner to www-data?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: you should discover for yourself setfacl in linux. It allows you to add users and groups for read, write and execute. Solved all the problems for me. No more owner problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Jenkins but if you make a mini shell script with :

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/xxx
```

And you run it at the end of your installation ?